# Can Javascript file access objects from Python objects running?

Tags: javascript, python

let say in Javascript file

```
_myclass = new MyClass();
```

MyClass is not defined anywhere in the Javascript.

However, MyClass is a class defined by setup.py and that setup.py is running.

```
setup(name             = 'MyClass',
  version          = '1.0',
  author           = '123',
```

when setup.py is not running then MyClass would be undefined in JAvascript.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: What module, template are you using? Is this a web application?

Comment: yes, javascript is for web app. but it's using object from Python running in background,

Comment: I'd say use something like `jsonp` to define it.

Comment: are you trying to be too smart, or you have a practical problem? if the latter, this sounds like an XY problem. describe *what* you really want to do (and not the *how* part)

Comment: Sorry, no, this doesn't make any sense. How is your "Python" being served? What data are you passing to Javascript? What does setup.py, which is used to install libraries, have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) framework. To simplify what it does, let say you can write any python class and/or function and pass it to an html [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/). So basically it allows you to put your python variables in your JS script.

Hope it helps!